# Close Foundation 5 alert box by clicking outside of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Foundation 5's Alert documentation (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) shows how to create an alert box that has an `x` in it so that once that's clicked it will close.

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
  <!-- Your content goes here -->
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

How do I add the feature that once you click outside of the alert box on the whitespace/canvas, it will also close similar to the Reveal Modal dialog boxes (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html?)

Comment: What you're looking for is to listen to the click event of <body> (or whatever surrounding area) then call that alert box's click.

Comment: Thanks Neps. That not as hairy as I thought it would be. I'm still learning when it comes to this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix, lead to by Neps comment.

```
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.close').click();
  });
```

I went with document instead of `body` and it seems to work. I changed the class to `class='close flash-data-alert'` and the click call to `$('.close.flash-data-alert').click();` since I'm using the alert to show Rails (I guess) flash messages.

Example

```
<div>
...
  <% flash.each do |severity, message| %>
    <div data-alert class='alert-box <%= severity %>' role='dialog'>
      <%= message %>
      <a href='#' class='close flash-data-alert'>&times;</a>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.close.flash-data-alert').click();
  });
</script>
```